# Formatear el contenido de un fichero JSON con python

Tags: python, archivo, formato

Estoy desarrollando un script en python 3.10 que lee el contenido de unos ficheros JSON y necesito, para el tiempo que esté desarrollando, que el contenido de los ficheros json aparezca formateado con sus tabulaciones para que me resulte más sencillo la lectura y comprensión de la estructura, ya que puede haber muchos tipos distintos de estructuras y en base a un flag en el nombre del fichero las debo interpretar.

El fichero original se ve tal que así:

```
{"Request":{"ErpCode":"026013/01","ErpNumberCreator":null,"Articles":[{"EAN":"0823007700180","ManufacturerCode":2,"ManufacturerName":"HELLA"}]},"Response":{"Data":[{"EAN":"0823007700180","ManufacturerCode":2,"ManufacturerName":"HELLA"}],"Success":true,"Message":"00:00:00.01"}}
```

Mientras que la idea es que al abrir el archivo en un editor de texto/código, se pueda ver así:

```
{
    "Request":
    {
        "ErpCode": "026013/01",
        "ErpNumberCreator": null,
        "Articles":
        [
            {
                "EAN": "0823007700180",
                "ManufacturerCode": 2,
                "ManufacturerName": "HELLA"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Response":
    {
        "Data":
        [
            {
                "EAN": "0823007700180",
                "ManufacturerCode": 2,
                "ManufacturerName": "HELLA"
            }
        ],
        "Success": true,
        "Message": "00:00:00.01"
    }
}
```

Comment: Y ¿Qué has intentado hacer? ¿Cuál es el problema puntual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El módulo `json` (que viene en la biblioteca estándar) puede leer ficheros y también escribirlos. Y a la hora de escribirlo se le pueden especificar ciertos parámetros sobre cómo quieres formatearlo.

En tu caso, si el fichero se llama `entrada.json`, puedes hacer:

```py
import json

with open("entrada.json") as f:
  data = json.load(f)

with open("salida.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Más información sobre qué puede hacer `json.dump()` [en su sección del manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)